# Would a pointer to a pointer to nil match against NULL?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, null

Example:

A validation method contains this check to see if an NSError object shall be created or not:

```
- (BOOL)validateCompanyName:(NSString *)newName error:(NSError **)outError {
    if (outError != NULL) {
        // do it...
```

Now I pass an NSError object, like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL ok = [self validateCompanyName:@"Apple" error:&error];
```

I'm not sure if this matches the check for not NULL. I think it's not NULL, since I believe NULL is not nil. Maybe someone can clear this up?

Comment: what happens if you hold down the Command key and double click on a `nil`? ;)

Comment: Then I get something very strange like #define nil NULL ;) haha...could have thinked about this. Yeah. same thing. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nil` (all lower-case) is a null pointer to an Objective-C object.

`Nil` (capitalized) is a null pointer to an Objective-C class.

`NULL` (all caps) is a null pointer to anything else.

Yet they all compile to `0`, so `(nil == Nil == NULL == 0)` (thanks Dave).

Comment: Or more simply put: `nil = Nil = NULL = 0`